# Android how to start an apk download from the notification drawer

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've an app that i can push notifications on to via GCM. I receive the notification in the notification drawer but when i click on it, an activity from the app is started(EntryActivity). What i'd like to happen is if the message in the notification is a url to the .apk file eg 'http://path_to_file.apk', then i'd like the file to start downloading.

Below is the code that generates the notification, is there something i need to add or change to start the download?

```
/**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);


        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EntryActivity.class);

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);     

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://path_to_file.apk"));
    notificationIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser",
                                "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
```